# CSS: When does -ms-overflow-style NOT apply?

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

There seem to be some situations in which -ms-overflow-style doesn't apply, even though I don't see any CSS that sets that property. The (awful IMO) auto-hiding behavior isn't happening, without using "-ms-overflow-style: scrollbar". Does anyone know what other DOM or CSS circumstances might cause this?

EDIT: I didn't make myself clear, apologies.

I work on a large app with a lot of dialogs that appear in a custom lightbox built on top of script.aculo.us. In Edge, in those dialogs, scrollbars on divs don't work, and dropdowns exhibit some harder to describe problems.

There are several striking things about those problems:

- Edge only
- Can be prevented my defeating Microsoft's auto-hiding scrollbars with this CSS: {-ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;}
- Only happens in those lightboxed dialogs

I was asking what defeats -ms-overflow-style because the problems appear to be the result of Edge's default behavior, which outside of those lightboxes, is being blocked by something. I was essentially asking what that something might be.

I don't want to "use" -ms-overflow-style, except to get rid of Edge's auto-hiding scrollbars, and only if I have to. Outside of those lightboxes, it seems not to be needed. I wondered why.

Does that make more sense?

Comment: This CSS property is proprietary and non-standard, and maybe even Microsoft has abandoned it now - I can't find a reference to it on [Microsoft Developers Network](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=%22-ms-overflow-style%22&pgArea=header&emptyWatermark=true&ac=4). I assume you only expect it to work on Edge. The former [MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441298.aspx) now redirects to a [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-ms-overflow-style) that says `Do not use it on production sites facing the Web`

Comment: The verdict from [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=-ms-overflow-style) seems to be that you can't use it. They don't show results from any browser.